# Finding rows that only have duplicate values in a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server called `Data`:

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith | 1234 |
| David | Smith | 3456 |
| Scott | Clark | 198 |
| Brian | Williams | 155 |
| Jeremy | Williams | 765 |

I need rows from `Data`, but **ONLY** the rows where the values in `ColB` appears more than once.

For example, I would want my query to return rows 1 and 2 since 'Smith' is repeated in `ColB`, and rows 4 and 5 to return since 'Williams' is repeated in `ColB`. Row 3 would NOT be returned since 'Clark' only appears once.

How would I go about writing this query? I am not too sure where to start. I have a feeling I will be using `COUNT` but not too sure of what else.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just another option is using `WITH TIES` in concert with `sign()` and the window function `sum() over()`

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
 From  Data
 Order by sign(sum(1) over (partition by ColB)-1) desc
```

Results

```
ColA    ColB        ColC
John    Smith       1234
David   Smith       3456
Brian   Williams    155
Jeremy  Williams    76
```

Comment: This is creative, thanks for introducing me to `with ties` :)

Comment: @Simeon Just another option available.  Would not suggest using it with a HUGE table.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to create a subquery that returns all `ColB` that appear more than once using `HAVING` after the group by, then selecting only the rows that those values appear in

```
with cte as ( 
 select ColB as [duplicate]
 from Data
 group by ColB
 having count(*) > 1
)

select * from Data where ColB in ( select duplicate from cte )
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `EXISTS` operator with correlated subquery as the following:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM data T
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM data D 
             WHERE D.ColB = T.ColB AND 
                   (D.ColA <> T.ColA OR D.ColC <> T.ColC)
            )
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xr8UqCi0).

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        colb,
        COUNT(*) AS dup
    FROM
        sales
    GROUP BY
        colb
)
SELECT
    cola
FROM
         data
    INNER JOIN cte ON data.colb = cte.colb
WHERE
    cte.colb > 1;
```